# Ionic / Angular REST call from array to localStorage weird naming behavior

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am coding an app in Ionic and am trying to get it as dynamic as possible.

Currently I have a bunch of REST calls being made and their results being stored in local storage.

The URI and the name to be used in localStorage are defined in an array.

The issue is this : when the $http.get method is successful, it storing each result under the last title in the array.

```
  var service = this;
  endpoints = {
    pilgrimages : "wp-json/wp/v2/pages?parent=9&per_page=100",
    toursOfIreland : "wp-json/wp/v2/pages?parent=15&per_page=100",
    escorted : "wp-json/wp/v2/pages?parent=11&per_page=100",
    schoolCollege : "wp-json/wp/v2/pages?parent=13&per_page=100"
  }

  this.retrieve = function() {
    for (var endpoint in endpoints) {
      // console.log(endpoint + " : " + endpoints[endpoint]);
      $http.get(baseUrl + endpoints[endpoint])
      .success(function(result, status){
        console.log(result);
        result.forEach(function(index){
          if ( index.page_thumb !== "" ){
            index.page_thumb = window.baseUrl + index.page_thumb;
          }
          if ( index.page_thumb == "" ){
            index.page_thumb = "img/no_image_available.jpg";
          }
          if (index.page_content !== "") {
            index.content.rendered = index.page_content;
          }
        });
        console.log(thisEndpoint + " completed");
        var result = JSON.stringify(result);
        window.localStorage.setItem(endpoint,result)
      })
    }
```

The console output reads as follows...

```
services.js:26 [Object, Object, Object]
services.js:38 schoolCollege completed
services.js:26 [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
services.js:38 schoolCollege completed
services.js:26 [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
services.js:38 schoolCollege completed
services.js:26 [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
services.js:38 schoolCollege completed
```

Thanks for the help !

Comment: yes, it will obviously be stored in random title(mostly last title), as the `for` loop updates the `endpoint` before `http` request gets completed

Comment: Ah I see, any ideas how to fix it ?

Comment: well i had similar scenario, i changed it to send only one request from UI and the processing was done on backend, helps in performance also, you will save a lot of calls, that was my solution which i implemented, if you can't implement this way then maybe you will have to make multiple requests without `for` loop

Comment: thanks for your comments, I figured a way around it.

Answer (score 1):

solved.

```
  var service = this;
  endpoints = {
    pilgrimages : "wp-json/wp/v2/pages?parent=9&per_page=100",
    toursOfIreland : "wp-json/wp/v2/pages?parent=15&per_page=100",
    escorted : "wp-json/wp/v2/pages?parent=11&per_page=100",
    schoolCollege : "wp-json/wp/v2/pages?parent=13&per_page=100"
  }

  this.retrieve = function() {
    for (var endpoint in endpoints) {
      var address = baseUrl + endpoints[endpoint]
          makeRequest(endpoint,address);
    }
    console.log("app updated on " + new Date())
    $rootScope.updated = new Date();
  }

  function makeRequest(endpoint,url) {
    $http.get(url)
    .success(function(result, status){
      console.log(result);
      result.forEach(function(index){
        if ( index.page_thumb !== "" ){
          index.page_thumb = window.baseUrl + index.page_thumb;
        }
        if ( index.page_thumb == "" ){
          index.page_thumb = "img/no_image_available.jpg";
        }
        if (index.page_content !== "") {
          index.content.rendered = index.page_content;
        }
      });
      console.log(endpoint + " completed");
      var result = JSON.stringify(result);
      window.localStorage.setItem(endpoint,result)
    })
  }
```